# putty interaction using VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros, putty

I just want to automate a putty task which I am doing 1000 times daily (more of a vague task).  the steps are
1.login to putty or plink
2.run a unix grep cmd in the plink or putty terminal.  getting the output result to a notepad.

As of now i am successful with 1st step by using below cmd

`"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" user@server.com -pw password`

how can I pass my `grep` cmd to putty and get the output to my local?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think putty let you do that but there is CLI alternative to putty called plink which let you run command in remote computer and save output in local computer. 
You can download plink from http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Here is sample code structure to connect to remote server, run grep command and save output to local computer.

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" user@server.com -pw password  "grep command here" > fileName.txt
```

If your Program Files needs admin access to write, move plink.exe to Desktop and run the command. You will see fileName.txt file in your desktop with output.

You can find more about plink in http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink.

I hope this post is helpful.